# ffmpeg copy some audio streams and re-encode some audio streams

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, encoding

**The Problem**

I have a mkv file that contains audio in a format that not all my devices support. To get full support, I want to copy that audio and convert it **while retaining** the original audio.

Input:

- mkv
- 4 *stereo* audio tracks

Output:

- **mka** (I only care about the audio)
- 2 *stereo* audio tracks (original, track 0 and 2 copied)
- 2 *stereo* audio tracks (converted, track 0 -> track 1, track 2 -> track 3)
- the original track 1 and 3 shall be discarded

**What I´ve found so far (using ffmpeg 6.1):**

To copy audio track 0 and 2, I can use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:a -c:a:0 copy -c:a:2 copy output.mka
```

And this command to change the audio format of track 0 to OPUS.

```
ffmpeg -i intput.mkv -map 0:a -mapping_family 1 -ac 6 -c:a:0 libopus -metadata:s:a:0 title='Opus 5.1' -metadata:s:a:0 language='eng' output.mka
```

I think I can remove the `-mapping_family 1 -ac 6` part, as I´m only dealing with stereo audio.

**The question:**

How can I combine both commands to get the following track layout?:

- track 0 (original, copied, metadata retained)
- track 1 (re-encode from track 0)
- track 2 (original, copied, metadata retained)
- track 3 (re-encode from track 2)

Comment: mapping `ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:2 -map 0:a:2 -c:0 copy -c:1 libopus -c:2 copy -c:3 libopus -metadata:s:0 title="aac 0" -metadata:s:1 title="Opus 1" -metadata:s:2 title="aac 2" -metadata:s:3 title="Opus 3" /tmp/out.mka`